Decidability of whether for a given $G$, $L(G)=\Sigma^+$? (or $L(G)=L$ where $L$ is fixed beforehand
If $G$ is a CFG, is it decidable whether $L(G)=\Sigma^+=\Sigma^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$? I have no idea which in direction to go. I feel like it is undecidable, but can't seem to find any proof. I thought about $\overline{VALCOMPS_{M,x}}$ and that doesn't seem to work as $\overline{VALCOMPS_{M,x}}$ is $\Delta^*$ if $M$ doesn't halt on $x$ and $\Delta^*\setminus\{\text{Some finite set}\}$ otherwise. So it remains to check whether $VALCOMPS_{M,x}=\{\epsilon\}$ which I am not sure if it is decidable. I don't feel it's decidable.
More generally, if $G$ is a CFG, and $L$ is some language (fixed beforehand), is it decidable whether $L(G)=L$? I know the claim is false for $L=\Sigma^*$, and true if $L$ is finite, but is it true for some infinite set that is not the universal language? If so, what's a characterization for such sets?
Help would be appreciated

You've mentioned, that you know that $L(G) = \Sigma^$ is undecidable.
Assume (BWOC) that you can decide $L(G) = \Sigma^+$, can you also decide $L(G) = \Sigma^$?
(Hint: Look at $G$s CNF)

It is decidable whether $\epsilon \in L(G)$.  Given a context-free grammar $G$, you can construct a new context-free grammar $G'$ such that $L(G')=L(G) \cap \Sigma^+$.  If $L(G')=\Sigma^+$ and $\epsilon \in L(G)$, then $L(G)=\Sigma^*$; if not, then $L(G) \ne \Sigma^*$.  Therefore, if it were decidable whether $L(G')=\Sigma^+$, it would be decidable whether _________ (you fill in the blank).  But it is known that it is undecidable whether $L(G)=\Sigma^*$.  Therefore, ______ (you fill in the blank).
I leave it to you to fill in the details and justify each of these steps.  This is your exercise, so it will be a good practice for you to fill in the blanks and justify each step.

It would be decidable whether $L(G)=\Sigma^*$... But it's undecidable. Therefore, $L(G')=\Sigma^+$ must be undecidable. Thanks
